# Determining if a file is managed code or not

Tags: windows, tools, dll, pe

How can I quickly tell if a EXE or DLL I have is managed code or not?

I spent some time recently trying to disassemble a file and then later learned through some traces in the code that I could have skipped all that work and just used ILspy. How can I avoid repeating that experience in the future?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A managed DLL / Application will have a primary dependency on MSCOREE.dll... So, if you open the DLL in Dependency Walker you have
> no problems in telling a managed library from an unmanaged one.
>
> ```
>     http://www.dependencywalker.com/
> ```

Quoted from [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?424454-Check-if-DLL-is-managed-or-not).

Other useful MSDN links:

- [How to tell if a function is managed code?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/how-to-tell-if-a-function-is-managed-code)
- [Exploring pe file headers using managed code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160202125049/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/kstanton/archive/2004/03/31/105060.aspx)

Comment: See answers from broadway and peter ferrie. Checking for an mscoree.dll dependency is somewhat reliable, but not 100%.

Comment: To confirm, I made [PoCs](https://code.google.com/p/corkami/source/detail?r=1595) that imports mscoree.dll and even have fake .NET-looking EntryPoint, but no .COM directory.

Comment: That's not a very constructive comment. I'm just trying to prove that COM directory is a more reliable indicator than imports or EntryPoint for this question.

Answer (score 27):

Check the dword at offset 0xE8 (32-bit) or 0xF8 (64-bit) in the PE header.  If it's non-zero, it's the pointer to the CLR header.  That's a managed file (you can't put random data there because direct .NET parsing support is built into XP and later, so the file won't load if the data aren't valid).  The presence of mscoree.dll is not enough in itself, because the application might be doing things with managed files but not be managed itself.

Comment: This answer deserves top billing.  Allows you to get the answer with NO extra tools besides your brain and a knowledge of the PE header.

Comment: The offset can be different depending whether it is a PE32 or PE32+.

Comment: @Veitch, I finally edited my answer to include that.

Comment: FYI This is equivalent to @broadway's answer and Karsten Hahn's answer: offset 0xe8 or 0xf8 is of the VirtualAddress of IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR.

Comment: @pts there is a significant difference: using the #define means a 32-bit program will recognise only a 32-bit program, 64-bit will only recognise 64-bit.  This is why I suggested using the hard-coded values.

Answer (score 13):

Checking `DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR].VirtualAddress` in the data directory portion of the PE header for a nonzero value is probably the fastest way.

`#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR 14   // COM Runtime descriptor`

References:

- [`IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680305.aspx)
- [Anatomy of a .NET Assembly – PE Headers](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/03/15/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/)

Comment: This is the method I use. The 14th member of the Data Directory array is IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR , since it isn't listed in the post. We should discourage absolute references like that.

Comment: a hexeditor has no concept of data directories, though, hence the absolute offset.

Comment: depends on the hex editor, really. 010 has PE templates.

Answer (score 7):

Manually, i prefer to observe the following signs in the **PE header**:

1- Presence of **mscoree!_CorExeMain** in the **import table**.

2- **VirtualAddress** and **Size** of the **CLR Header**/**Com Descriptor** data directory are set. Size set to **0x48**.

3- Size of the **Base Relocation** data directory set to **0x0C** i.e. Only one fixup.

Also, one minor sign is:

4- **SectionAlignment** set to **0x2000**.

Answer (score 6):

Try opening it in ILSpy first. It should tell you if the assembly isn't managed.

Comment: This implies that ILSpy is able to open it, which is not always the case.

Comment: ILSpy has a specific message if the assembly isn't managed. If it fails to load for another reason I'm sure there's a different message :) Could you show me a managed assembly which ILSpy says isn't managed?

Comment: If it fails to load the PE (with managed code or not), it gives some Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader error. [TinyNet](https://code.google.com/p/corkami/source/browse/trunk/src/PE/tinynet.asm?r=1596#44) is using the common malware trick of having a small NumOfRVA to hide its COM directory - which fails ILSpy - even though it's using managed code.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to peter ferries answer, some python code to check for the same:

```
import sys

def unpack(byte):
    return sum([
        ord(b) << (8 * i) for i, b in enumerate(byte)
    ])

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print >> sys.stderr, "No input file given!"
else:
    myfile = sys.argv[1]

    with open(myfile, "r") as f:
        f.seek(0x3c)
        peoffset = unpack(f.read(2))
        optoffset = peoffset + 24
        f.seek(optoffset)
        magic = f.read(2)
        offset = -1
        if magic == '\x0b\x01':
            offset = 208 + optoffset
        else:
            offset = 224 + optoffset
        f.seek(offset)
        clr_address = unpack(f.read(4))
        if clr_address == 0:
            print "no managed executable"
        else:
            print "managed executable"
```

Answer (score 4):

The fastest heuristic method I found so far was to check whether it imports `mscoree.dll`.

In the version resource of `mscoree.dll` Microsoft calls it: *Microsoft .NET Runtime Execution Engine*.

Comment: No, this won't work, as many other executables also import from mscoree.dll that are not managed assemblies.

Comment: @Abel examples please.

Comment: it's 8 years ago :D, but let's try: `mscoree.dll` could be linked by any compiler (just create a C++ prj) without it becoming a CLR binary.The inverse is also true, [some .NET binaries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli) do not have a link to `mscoree.dll`. And apparently, it may be `mscoreei.dll` in [some cases](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/IJW-activation.md). I'm not sure about reference assemblies. I'd rely on PE headers, which will give you the .NET version info and CLR.

Comment: Thanks @Abel ... much appreciated. I am actually really interested (again) in this topic, that's why I asked.

Comment: I see :). That said, I just checked all loaded binaries that reference mscoree.dll in-memory. The exception on my machine seems to be `procexp64.exe`, which has a reference to `mscoree.dll` but is not a CLI assembly. Everything else follows the rule "if it has mscoree.dll, then it is .NET".

Answer (score 4):

CorFlags.exe is a utility that ships with the Windows SDK. Execute that passing in the name of the file in question and if it is a managed file it will tell you what version of the Dotnet framework it uses and whether the file is all managed code or mixed mode, whether it is signed, and a few other useful bits of info.

Answer (score 1):

## Cross-platform C# solution

Use [`PEReader.HasMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.pereader.hasmetadata?view=net-7.0):

```csharp
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion);
        
        var currentAssemblyIsManaged = IsManaged(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location) ?? false;
        Console.WriteLine($"The currently executing assembly is {(currentAssemblyIsManaged ? "" : "not ")}managed");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Here are some unmanaged assemblies:");
        var unmanagedAssemblies = ((string)AppContext.GetData("TRUSTED_PLATFORM_ASSEMBLIES"))
            .Split(OperatingSystem.IsWindows() ? ';' : ':')
            .Select(path => Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
            .Distinct()
            .SelectMany(directory => Directory.GetFiles(directory))
            .Where(file => IsManaged(file) == false);
        foreach (var path in unmanagedAssemblies)
        {
            Console.Write('\t');
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
    }
    
    static bool? IsManaged(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            using var peReader = new PEReader(stream);
            return peReader.HasMetadata;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Probably not an assembly, but maybe the file is merely inaccessible at the moment?
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qkujEM)

Output from .NET Fiddle:

```
Unix 5.15.0.1024
The currently executing assembly is managed
Here are some unmanaged assemblies:
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libmscordbi.so
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libcoreclrtraceptprovider.so
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libcoreclr.so
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libmscordaccore.so
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.so
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libclrgc.so
    /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/libclrjit.so
```

Output on a Windows machine:

```
Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22621.0
The currently executing assembly is managed
Here are some unmanaged assemblies:
        C:\Users\____\bin\Debug\net7.0\ConsoleApp22.exe
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\clretwrc.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\clrgc.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\clrjit.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\coreclr.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\createdump.exe
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\hostpolicy.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\mscordaccore.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\mscordaccore_amd64_amd64_7.0.523.17405.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\mscordbi.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\mscorrc.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\msquic.dll
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\System.IO.Compression.Native.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

When examining the VirtualAddress property of the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR within the Data Directory of a running process, one may observe the manifestation of native code as .NET. This occurrence is attributed to the dynamic execution of .NET modules during runtime. However, it is imperative to consider.