# How does the OS distinguish between executable types

Tags: windows, executable

Executable files created through managed framework like .Net have `.exe` extension whereas application created through languages like C++ also has `.exe` extension. How does the OS knows whether to run the application through managed framework like .Net or directly ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The COM Descriptor Data Directory (DD 14) is used to lookup the COR20 structure. This is how you can tell the difference between a managed executable and a native executable.

See [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/determining-if-a-file-is-managed-code-or-not/) for more information. Also see this introduction to the [dotnet file format](http://www.ntcore.com/files/dotnetformat.htm) for an overview.